# need to extract all the content between two string in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, text-extraction, data-extraction

I have data in pandas dataframe. i need to extract all the content between the string which starts with "Impact Factor:"  and ends with "&#". If the content doesn't  have "Impact Factor:" i want null in that row of the dataframe

this is sample data from a single row.

Save to EndNote online &# Add to Marked List &# Impact Factor: Journal 2 and Citation Reports 500 &# Other Information &# IDS Number: EW5UR &#

I want the content like the below in a dataframe .
Journal 2 and Citation Reports 500 
Journal 6 and Citation Reports 120
Journal 50 and Citation Reports 360
Journal 30 and Citation Reports 120

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can just use a regular expression here:

```
result = your_df.your_col.apply(lambda x: re.findall('Impact Factor:(.*?)&#',x))
```

You may want to strip white spaces too in which case you could use:

```
result = your_df.your_col.apply(lambda x: re.findall('Impact Factor:\s*(.*?)\s*&#',x))
```